# Properly downgrading from cuda 10.1 and driver 440

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, nvidia, gpu, stability

This is my first question so if I missed anything please let me know. My knowledge of linux is quite weak at this point.

I am running ubuntu 18.04 with 1080ti gpus (x2). This is with a threadripper 2990wx and 128gigs of compatible ram (if that is somehow related and I am wrong).

For the last few weeks now, I have been attempting to use cuda 10.1 with nvidia driver 440. I have repetitive crashes; my firefox/chrome tabs will crash, followed by my mouse becoming irresponsive (clicks not working but seeing the cursor move), and my terminal will not activate (will open with flashing cursor, but no user@pc and commands dont work). I had thought to post crash reports, but saw other posts with similar issues and am basically concluding that driver 440 is the culprit (apparently this issue persists from driver 430).

What is the proper way to roll back, without issue, to a driver that is more stable with my configuration? I am ok to roll back my cuda version as well at this point. I feel like I have been beta testing and would prefer a stable build so that I can get back to work.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Before downgrading, please make sure you have the [latest NVIDIA driver, version 440.82](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/159360/en-us), direct from NVIDIA, not from a PPA.

2) If upgrading to the very latest stable driver direct from NVIDIA does not help, uninstall with

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run --uninstall
```

3) If you installed  nvidia-current or nvidia-current-updates uninstall them with

```
sudo apt -y remove nvidia-current nvidia-current-updates
```

4) Rename *xorg.conf* to *xorg.conf.old* then reboot, which will use nouveau instead.

5) Once rebooted, download and install [390.132](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/153832/en-us) or [418.113](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/153717/en-us) since you've read unhappy things about 430 onward.

6) Test stability with those drivers before making any changes to [cuda](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cuda-binaries.1.html). Run lots of apps simultaneously, including [stress](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/stress.1.html) or equivalent with a low-to-moderate workload while manually using other apps. Keep an eye on results of [free](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/free.1.html)-m or other equivalent tool while you do, and increase the stress workload until most of the swap is in use.

Comment: Here is the site that I used to guide my installation of cuda: https://medium.com/@exesse/cuda-10-1-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-d04f89287130 Is anything about it wrong? Perhaps my installation is flawed (again)? I notice that here they use a PPA. This was from a fresh minimal install of ubuntu. Before installing I installed gcc from terminal.

Comment: If they use a PPA, I recommend using that PPA and following their instructions once the NVIDIA driver issue is resolved.

Comment: Ok, I actually flashed my system. It was too unstable. So would you recommend I install the driver first then cuda? Is there an order for the commands? I am not confident in how I am going about this. Following their instructions will force 440 onto my system with cuda.

Comment: I reinstalled driver 435 (proprietary, not open source like 440) and cuda 10.1. I will report back if there are any issues. Here is the guide I used for installation for anyone in a similar situation: https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-gpu-installation-on-ubuntu-18-4-9b12230a1d31

Comment: Unfortunately I spoke too soon - it didnt work. I may just install cuda 10.1 from the site with the driver it recommends (418). Not really sure what else to do and I am at my wits end. Another weird thing, Im running Ubuntu 18.04.4 and the kernel isnt listed on the cuda website....

Comment: I have now installed driver 418.113 with cuda 10.1, all from nvidia (not PPA). I reverted to Ubuntu 18.04.3 prior to installation (with minimum install), since it seems that 18.04.4 is not listed on cudas compatibility list. When you say test stability, how can I do that?

Comment: As of now it seems like the stability problems are gone. I have yet to install pycharm so it may change once I do. I wonder why there is so little discussion around this issue, it seems like nvidia has somewhat poor documentation regarding compatibility (or I missed it, not sure). I accepted your answer but will come back to report what happens.